# PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have created an aggregation query [on mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VXWSVeRrkvX) as also shown with the following data:

```
    [
        {
         postId: "1",
         comment: {
            text_sentiment: "positive",
            topic: "A"
         }
        },

        {
         postId: "2",
         comment: {
            text_sentiment: "negative",
            topic: "A"
         }
        },
        {
         postId: "3",
         comment: {
          text_sentiment: "positive",
          topic: "B"
         }
       },

    {
     postId: "4",
     comment: {
        topic: "B"
     }
    }
  ]
```

In the data above `postId = 4` does not have `text_sentiment` key inside but every other doc has.

Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
        //    surveyId: "e6d38e1ecd",
        "comment.topic": {
            $exists: 1
        },
        
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
        _id: {
            topic: "$comment.topic",
            text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
        },
        total: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        postIds: {
            $push: "$postId"
        }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
        _id: "$_id.topic",
        total: {
            $sum: "$total"
        },
        text_sentiments: {
            $push: {
            k: "$_id.text_sentiment",
            v: "$total"
            }
        },
        postIds: {
            "$push": "$postIds"
        }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
        topic: "$_id",
        topicOccurance: "$total",
        sentiment: {
            "$arrayToObject": "$text_sentiments"
        },
        postIds: {
            $setUnion: [
            {
                $reduce: {
                input: "$postIds",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    "$$this"
                    ]
                }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
        "topicOccurance": -1
        }
    }
    ])
```

Running this gives `query failed: (Location40392) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1`.

How can I know if each comment has both `topics` and `comment` before this aggregation could be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator to provide a default value and then post-process your results after aggregation is done:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {                
            topic: "$comment.topic",
            text_sentiment: {
                "$ifNull": [
                    "$comment.text_sentiment",
                    "unknown"
                ]
            }
        },
        total: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        postIds: {
            $push: "$postId"
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W2olaGrwb0u)

EDIT:alternatively, you can use [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) to check whether `text_sentiments` array contains both values:

```
{
    $match: {
        "text_sentiments.k": {
            $all: [
                "positive",
                "negative"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jalzB2klMBE)

Comment: This sounds good. What if I want to only run the aggregation if each `comment` has the `topic` and `text_sentiment` field? Is there a way to check that?

Comment: @SuhailGupta - modified my answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: Could you help answering a linked question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952879/adding-a-match-query-with-mongodb-lookup