# Adding a $match query with mongodb lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am pulling data from 2 collections as shown in [this MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AaDJ_j0x05e). While pulling the data from the second collection, I want to create a match on `tag`, such that only those posts are returned that have the particular `tag` associated with them.

Here is the query that I created:

```js
db.Vote.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            comment: {
                $ne: null,
            },
            "comment.topic": {
                $exists: 1,
                $regex: ".",
                $options: "i",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                topic: "$comment.topic",
                text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment",
            },
            total: {
                $sum: 1,
            },
            postIds: {
                $push: "$postId",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.topic",
            total: {
                $sum: "$total",
            },
            text_sentiments: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.text_sentiment",
                    v: "$total",
                },
            },
            postIds: {
                $push: "$postIds",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            topic: "$_id",
            topicOccurance: "$total",
            sentiment: {
                $arrayToObject: "$text_sentiments",
            },
            postIds: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$postIds",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"],
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            topicOccurance: -1,
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Post",
            localField: "postIds",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "tag",
        },
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            postIds: {
                $setUnion: "$postIds",
            },
            tag: {
                $setUnion: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$tag",
                        in: "$$this.tag",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
]);
```

The result looks similar to:

```
{
    "_id" : "Collaboration & Teamwork",
    "topic" : "Collaboration & Teamwork",
    "topicOccurance" : 355,
    "sentiment" : {
        "Negative" : 102,
        "Neutral" : 132,
        "Positive" : 121
    },
    "postIds" : [
        "0iWc2U8FVz",
        "3Qzysi2cXD",
        "3hRx7qAvcb",
        "BsrTDkHmkE",
        "LT2HE2uEa5",
        "Qw0WcUBcnY",
        "U72zss2Af5",
        "V9DcRcSawi",
        "hNwFVJ2bBk"
    ],
    "tag" : [
        [
            "Engagement"
        ],
        [
            "Environment"
        ],
        [
            "Feedback & Recognition"
        ],
        [
            "Leadership"
        ],
        [
            "Management"
        ],
        [
            "Meaningful Work"
        ],
        [
            "Open Text"
        ]
    ],
    "totalDocs" : 39
}
```

After the `tag` match, the response will only have `Posts` that have `tag = foo`. How can I do that?

[Mongo DB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AaDJ_j0x05e) : This has the above query with the sample data.

Comment: You can use [full $lookup syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection) to define a subquery pipeline on the second collection and apply filters there

Comment: @AlexBlex Could you show an example or a sample playground?

Comment: @AlexBlex The response should only contain posts that have a particular tag.

Comment: Sorry, the query is too long to analyse. Id be happy to update it on the playground if it was reduced to the part that's relevant to the question. I believe you already have few answers that show an example of the full $lookup syntax

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: If you want the query to return the `sentiment` and `postIds` that match the tag criteria, you can use the `$lookup` on an earlier phase.

```
db.Vote.aggregate([
  {$match: {"comment": {$ne: null},
      "comment.topic": {$exists: 1, $regex: ".", $options: "i"}}
  },
  {$lookup: {
      from: "Post",
      let: {postId: "$postId"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$and: [{$eq: ["$_id", "$$postId"]}, {$in: ["a", "$tag"]}]}}}
      ],
      as: "tag"
    }
  },
  {$match: {$expr: {$gt: [{$size: "$tag"}, 0]}}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {topic: "$comment.topic", text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"},
      total: {$sum: 1}, postIds: {$push: "$postId"}}
  },
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.topic",
      total: {$sum: "$total"},
      text_sentiments: {
        $push: {k: "$_id.text_sentiment", v: "$total"}},
      postIds: {$push: "$postIds"}
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      topic: "$_id",
      topicOccurance: "$total",
      sentiment: {$arrayToObject: "$text_sentiments"},
      postIds: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$postIds",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$sort: {"topicOccurance": -1}},
  {$addFields: {postIds: {$setUnion: "$postIds"},
      tag: {$setUnion: {$map: {input: "$tag", in: "$$this.tag"}}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lQ6MaAm48LK)

Comment: But this will still return the post with id's that have the tag `b`. That should not happen.

Comment: This still returns the `postids` that do not have the particular `tag`.  For instance check here https://mongoplayground.net/p/NyeVBryzFjj It should not return post id `2`

Comment: So, it should return the `sentiment` , `postIds`  that match the `tag` criteria.

Comment: Updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in the look up it should help you

```
{
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "Post",
           let: { tagInit: "$tag", postidInit: "$postIds" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$_id",  "$$postids" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$tag", "$$tagInit" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           as: "tag"
         }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).